# urllib2 gets an http code of 404 on site where firefox gets code 200

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape data off an internal website with urllib2. When I run

```
try:
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(urlBase)
    data = resp.read()
except HTTPError as e1:
    print("HTTP Error %d trying to reach %s" % (e1.code, urlBase))
except URLError as e2:
    print("URLError %d" % e2.code)
    print(e2.read())
```

I get an HTTPError with e1.code of 404. If I navigate to the site on Firefox and use the developer tools I see an HTTP code of 200. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

**Edit 1** Before I call this, I also install an empty proxy handler so urllib2 doesn't try to use the proxy settings set by my shell:

```
handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.intall_opener(opener)
```

**Edit 2** FWIW the url I'm navigating to is an apache index and not an html document. However, the status code as read by Firefox is still saying HTTP/1.1 Status 200

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens to me after I've been using an HTTP proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).  In my case, The fix is simply opening and closing the HTTP proxy.

Comment: I've edited my post to include how I'm removing the proxy that urllib2 detects so I can access this internal site. Is there any other way I can close the proxy to remove this erroneous 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a function inside the try I stripped out was trying to access another page that was triggering the 404 error.